# Cannot use Crud\Core\Objec

Tags: php, api

I was not using the API for long time and then we switched to PHP 7.2. It shows the error below. OS is Ubuntu 14.04.6 .

I am a beginner and have no idea where to start from. I'd be thankful if someone could tell me where to start from.

`composer.json` looks like this:

> ```
> "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.5.9", 
>     "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.2",
>     "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
>     "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
>     "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
>     "friendsofcake/crud":"~4.0"
> ```
>
> Fatal error: Cannot use Crud\Core\Object as Object because 'Object' is
>   a special class name in
>   /www/htdocs/w0555555e/api.website.com/vendor/friendsofcake/crud/src/Listener/BaseListener.php
>   on line 4

Answer (score 0):

FriendsOfCake 4.0 doesn't support PHP 7.2. Since `Object` has become a keyword in PHP 7.2, FriendsOfCake can't use it as a class name anymore.

This was fixed in a later version of `FriendsOfCake` as referenced in [this pull request](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud/pull/549) on GitHub.

Try updating to [version 5.2.0](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud/releases/tag/5.2.0) or later by updating the line:

```json
    "friendsofcake/crud":"~4.0"
```

to:

```json
    "friendsofcake/crud":"~5.2.0"
```

and then running:

```dos
composer update
```

You may need to update some other dependencies as well.

Comment: Thanks.I followed what described in the pull request. now error is : ```"Warning (2): count() [<a href='php.net/function.count'>function.count</a>]: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable [CORE/src/Database/QueryCompiler.php, line 128]"``` Do you mean i need to change the text on line 2 of ```composer.json``` in vendor/friendsofcake/crud from ```"name":"friendsofcake/crud"``` > ```"name":"friendsofcake/crud":"~5.2.0"```  
I also acessed via SSH and opened the api directory and ran ```composer update``` and here is the response ```bash: composer: command not found```

Comment: You don't need to manually apply the changes in the pull request. Just install `composer` on the system and run `composer update` after changing line 7 in `composet.json`.